# Etymology of "yochevetzville"?

Tags: etymology

I've heard several Ashkenazic Jews (particularly those from the Midwest), both religious and secular, who use the word "yochevetzville" as synonymous with "nowhere". (e.g. "Of course he can't find shidduchim; he lives out in yochevetzville".)

What's the etymology of this word?

Comment: on my map it is a suburb of yenemzvelt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Mr. Gale’s parents had a sense of humor. “Yah-Chupetz-Ville” is none other than Sholom Aleichem’s Yehupetz, the fictional name given by the great Yiddish writer to the Ukrainian capital of Kiev, then part of Czarist Russia, in which he and his family lived for several years, and in and near which many of his stories take place.

source: http://forward.com/articles/126662/signposts-to-the-middle-of-nowhere/

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't quite explain how it got into the Midwestern Jewish vernacular, though.

Comment: @Shmuel Brin You probably heard the word "yente" used by the same people. Yente as a pejorative comes from secular yiddish theater yet somehow the heimishe oilem adopted it